# AssetManager.get() returns null even if my file has been loaded (Android Studio, libGDX, Java)

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I'm using libGDX's AssetManager, I have checked that my files have been loaded using the .update() method. Note that my boolean *loaded* is true once AssetManager.update() returns true (which means everything has been loaded).

```
if(loaded)
{
    if(player == null && walls == null)
    {
        player = new Player(this);
        walls = new WallList(this);
    }
    //unrelated stuff
}
```

My player object uses a texture and it works just fine.
But my walls object also uses a texture but it crashes. Here's my setup (in my WallList constructor)

```
//unrelated stuff
this.colors = new HashMap<Color, String>();
this.spawningColor = Color.red;

colors.put(Color.red, "sqr_wall_red");

for(int i = 0; i < wallCountNeeded; i++)
{
    this.add(new Wall(getTextureFromColor(spawningColor), i*wallWidth, 0));
}
```

In the code above, I make a HashMap and assign "sqr_wall_red" which is also the name of the png. I then call TextureFromColor to get the Texture from the AssetManager while using Color.Red as parameter.

```
private Texture getTextureFromColor(Color color)
{
    return game.getAssetManager().get("data/Sprites/" + colors.get(color) + ".png", Texture.class);
}
```

And I get this error

> Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at com.cedric.game.geometry.WallList.getTextureFromColor(WallList.java:45)
>       at com.cedric.game.geometry.WallList.(WallList.java:39)

I'm pretty confident in the fact that the path is alright since I load it like this

```
assetManager.load("data/Sprites/sqr_wall_red.png", Texture.class);
```

and if I print the path I'm using for assetManager.get()

```
System.out.println("data/Sprites/" + colors.get(spawningColor) + ".png");
```

I get this as an output (which matches the exact input in the assetManager.load()

> data/Sprites/sqr_wall_red.png

I think I have provided sufficient information in order to resolve my issue, but if you need more I will gladly show more.

Comment: What is line 45 in `WallList.java`?

Comment: return game.getAssetManager().get("data/Sprites/" + colors.get(color) + ".png", Texture.class);

Comment: There are at least 3 possible places in that line of code that can cause an NPE: `game`, `getAssetManager()`, and `colors`. You need to determine which one it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
return game.getAssetManager().get("data/Sprites/" + colors.get(color) + ".png", Texture.class);
```

There are 3 possible places in that line of code that can cause an NPE: `game`, `getAssetManager()`, and `colors`. You need to determine which one it is.